# debugging is not supporting in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to java.

I have installed the decompiling plugin to the eclipse. My project contains some external
  jars like spring mvc jars.I have opened one of the predefined class from one jar file using decompiler.
  Its corresponding .class file is opened and this .class file does not support debugging.

How can i debug that class?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to look how the debugging happens first.

- The IDE actually does not do any debugging. Its just uses the debug information provided by java at run time.
- When you run your program in **debug mode**, the java generates certain **additional information** in the class file to be used by the Runtime. On command prompt, you can do this by invoking `-g` option. e.g.  `javac -g YourClass.java`
- In short, class from the jar file may not have the debugging information as it was not compiled with debugging option.

So, to get you working, what you do is to re-compile the decompiled source and use that for debugging.

Here is relevant [link](http://cscarioni.blogspot.in/2010/12/understanding-how-java-debug-works.html) your can refer to.

Comment: I hava a doubt that,  .java files support debugging whereas .class files does not support debugging.

Comment: As I mentioned, the debugging information is put into the class file by the compiler.