# when is debugging work for java

Tags: java, debugging

I am new to java.I have a doubt that only ".java" files supports debugging whereas the
    ".class" files does not supports debugging in IDE.

Can you please suggest an answer?

Comment: add source files of the .class files to the debugger

Comment: You can't debug code without having the source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [debugging is not supporting in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377586/debugging-is-not-supporting-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Most IDE's (I know eclipse does, and pretty sure IntelliJ and netbeans do) will allow you to step through the processing of a class file, however they won't let you see what code is being executed, however you can see the variables in use. However to get there you will need to add a breakpoint in your code, and step down to the relevant class file. If you can attach the source, it will let you see the code being executed, as well as add a breakpoint directly in the file in question.